# C++ flush problem: why some text output before the buffer is full after using setvbuf

Tags: c++

1. After gdb run to the breakpoint at `fflush`, the screen prints "1" and "2";
2. After running fflush, the screen prints "3"

I cannot understand why it doesn't print "2" and "3" at the same time. _IOFBF does not mean it flushes the buffer after the buffer reaches the limit size? (Ubuntu 18.04)

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main()
{
 
   char buff[40960];
 
   memset( buff, '\0', sizeof( buff ));
 
   fprintf(stdout, "print test 1\n");    // 1
   setvbuf(stdout, buff, _IOFBF, 40960);    
 
   fprintf(stdout, "print test 2\n");    // 2
   fprintf(stdout, "print test 3\n");    // 3
   fflush( stdout );
 
   fprintf(stdout, "print before exit\n");
 
   sleep(5);
 
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use English rather than Chinese so that other people can understand your text in printf.

Comment: since you switch to fully buffered after (1), it is to be expected that the runtime no longer looks for newlines even in case the output device is a terminal. So we might expect that both (2) and (3) are kept in the (sufficiently large) buffer until flush. Still, this is an impementation detail. IMO the standard does not prohibit premature flushing? I read that definition as like, "_IOFBF does not mean it flushes the buffer **only** after the buffer reaches the limit size."

Comment: thanks for translating, but now it is even more confusing because the numbers in the output don't align with those in the commented statements :)

Comment: C or C++? They are different languages.

Comment: Cee, would you please provide some official document for reference. Thank you for your help.

Comment: use `char buff[40960] = { 0 }` instead of memset

Answer (score 0):

You are in uncharted territory because you set the buffer after writing to stdout. [From the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf)

> This function may only be used after stream has been associated with an open file, but before any other operation (other than a failed call to setbuf/setvbuf).

So after misusing setvbuf, one can't expect a precise behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This function runs correctly after the statement "print test 1" deleted.